# PHP GD image library shows empty box / broken image

Tags: php, image-processing, vagrant, gd

I am having the exact same problem as this SO, which unfortunately did not receive any answers:
[PHP GD - Empty box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516499/php-gd-empty-box)

I would like to start using the PHP GD image library and have attempted to run example code from the [documentation for imagecreate](http://pt2.php.net/imagecreate). I am using [Mercury Vagrant (HGV)](https://github.com/wpengine/hgv) for testing.

**Example:**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Running this produces a broken image or empty box with a solid border. The only information in the developer console is:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   image/png: "http://hhvm.hgv.test/stats/". Navigated to
>   http://hhvm.hgv.test/stats/

Removing the above code and inserting an if statement to check for the GD library shows that it is installed.

**GD Check:**

```
  if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) {
      echo "PHP GD library is installed on your web server";
  } else {
      echo "PHP GD library is NOT installed on your web server";
  }
```

**Output:**

> "PHP GD library is installed on your web server"